# submit without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I  am trying to submit data to the db without refreshing the page using jquery and php 
But  I guess  there is something I get wrong in my code , its works nicely if I do not apply Jquery :
Bellow is my code  am using .

```
<!---Insert into database -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chatbutton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "insertchatmessages.php",
            success: function () {}
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!---Insert into database ends here  -->

</head>
<body>
<table class="chattable" id="chattable" border="0">
<tr><td><div id="load_tweets">

</div></td></tr>
<form id ="chatform" action="?" method="post"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class ="chattext" type ="text" name="message"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="chatbutton" class="chatbutton" type="submit" value="send" name ="submit">
</div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML (this is derived from your code but modified to work in jsfiddle):

```
<table class="chattable" id="chattable" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="load_tweets"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form id ="chatform" action="/echo/html/" method="post"> <!-- your action should point to your php (insertchatmessages.php) -->
            <input type="hidden" name="html" value="This is sample text to show that this works!"/> <!-- for jsfiddle test only. remove this in your code. -->
            <input class ="chattext" type ="text" name="message" />
            <input class="chatbutton" class="chatbutton" type="submit" value="send" name ="submit" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chatform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this),
        data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
             data: data,
             type: $form.attr("method"),
             url: $form.attr("action"),
             success: function(data){
                  $("#load_tweets").html("<p>"+data+"</p>");
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/6vxMs/6/

Notes: I have made slight modifications to your code to make it work on jsfiddle, you will have to change it back to make it work in your setup.

Comment: I did exactly but it does not work maybe this line i have to change it how do u see. <form id ="chatform" action="?" method="post">

Comment: I'll change my answer to a full example and provide instructions.

Comment: Updated my answer with a more detailed example, a working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/6vxMs/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot but the page still blinks but to work it does but I don t want it to blink on submission

Comment: @Musa there might be something else causing this, would you be able to give me a link to your actual page?

Comment: at darshanags  thanks a lot kingmusa5 @gmail.com email me I will send u the files please they are off line

Answer (score 3):

`.chatbutton` is a submit button. When you click it, the jQuery handler fires, and then the form submits (which is the browser's default behavior). In your jQuery script you must call `preventDefault()`:

```
$('.chatbutton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// rest of your code
```

Better, assign a handler to the form submit function (but still you need to prevent default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Use `submit` jquery function.

```
$('#chatform').submit(function() { });
```

**Complete JS Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#chatform').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "random.php",
            success: function (response)
            {
                //do after response.
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will be helful

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chatbutton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            data: $('chatform').serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            url: "insertchatmessages.php",
            success: function () {}
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple user e.preventDefault() in start of your onclick call, it is used when you want to stop the default behavior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.chatbutton').click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "insertchatmessages.php",
            success: function () {}
        });
    });
});
</script>
```